# Brief description of commands in selenium testing

Tags: selenium, command

Hi i am new to selenium Testing till now i worked on Manual testing now i want to know about the mostly used commands and their description too. No Guidance is provided for me in the office

Answer (score 0):

Selenium documentation can be found @ http://seleniumhq.org/docs/

Apart from that, user forums are a good point startups